# Dart: cannot convert List<dynamic> to List<Map<String, dynamic>> Json_Table

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to parse data from a Rest API inside a Dart/Flutter application. The JSON contains a field called budgets at the root, which contains a list of Words. I want to get a List from this JSON and showing table from the Json with the package json_table.

```
class _PresupuestoPageState extends State<PresupuestoPage> {

  List <Map<String, dynamic>> _data;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Presupuesto"),
        centerTitle: false
      ),
      body: Container(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: _data != null
            ? JsonTable(
                _data,
              )
            : Text("Loading..."),
      ),
    );
  }

Future<void> fetchData() async {
    try {
      final response =
          await http.get("http://pr_laravel.loc/api/budgets");
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        print(response.body);
        setState(() {
          _data = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;
        });
      } else {
        print("Some error: ${response.statusCode}");
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change type of your `_data` from `List <Map<String, dynamic>>` to `List <dynamic>`.

Comment: This send me this error: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<dynamic>' in type cast

Comment: that's because you're using the list items which are dynamic as Map try to cast each list item toMap()

Answer (score 0):

```
List<YourModel> temp = _data.map((data) => YourModel.fromJson(data)).toList();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.